# How to extract the value of Excel

Tags: python, excel

I have an Excel sheet, where is entered post query, how can I use Python to read and extract certain attributes of the query in Excel and copy this to another column?

I don't know what dictionary I can use.

For example in cell Excel is results of post query. How can I extract the value of bifloor (7.5) and to write it to another column?

```
{"id":"03CD2B3C22558D83","imp": \[{"id":"03CD2B3C22558D83","video":{"mimes": \["video/mp4","video/x-flv","application/x-shockwave-flash"\],"minduration":3,"maxduration":300,"protocols": \[1,2,3,4,5,6\],"w":1920,"h":1080,"startdelay":0,"sequence":1,"boxingallowed":1,"api": \[1,2\]},"bidfloor":7.5,"bidfloorcur":"USD"}\],"app
```

I don't know what dictionary I can use

Comment: Please, check [ask]. How/why is this value (from POST request) stored in Excel? It looks like JSON but malformed - e.g. the \ chars. But anyway - why do you write it in Excel in the first place

Comment: Otherwise - the value for key `imp` being list of dicts suggest there might be more than one element with respective `bidfloor` value.

Comment: I used this code import openpyxl wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('/storage/emulated/0/Download/Log.xlsx') sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1') ws = wb.active df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.values) for cell in ws['C']: print(cell.value) but i don't know how i can search the value and save it in other column

Answer (score 0):

Use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to read the Excel file. Then you can perform some data validation in Python to get your value.

Comment: Please, don't speculate. This is JSON, if written correctly, what _data validation ... to get your value_

Comment: I used this code
 import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('/storage/emulated/0/Download/Log.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
ws = wb.active
df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.values)

for cell in ws['C']:
    print(cell.value) but i don't know how i can search the value and save it in other column